# Add routing to MdDialog for Angular2

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material2, angular-router

I need to add routing to an MdDialog component, and I am not sure what the best way to approach this problem is.

Currently, while on foo page (`www.app.com/foo/1`), the user can click a button and it will open an MdDialog component, bar.

What I want to do is, upon opening the MdDialog, it will append `/bar/:id` to the component. So, for example it will be something like `www.app.com/foo/1/bar/1`. The goal is for the user to have a shareable link that can lead to foo and then open the MdDialog.

So far, this is how my app is structured.

```
app/
  app.component.html <- <router-outlet> is found here
  app.component.ts
  app.module.ts

  foo/
    foo-routing.module.ts
    foo.component.html
    foo.component.ts
    foo.module.ts

    bar/
      bar.component.html <- This bar component file for the MdDialog
      bar.component.ts

  baz/ <- Another section of the website with it's own routing
    baz-routing.module.ts
    baz.component.html
    baz.component.ts
    baz.module.ts
    ...
```

Currently in my `foo-routing.module.ts`, I have this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'foo/:fooId',
    component: FooComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'bar/:barId',
        component: BarDialogComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

However, this does not work. All this does is open the module, reroutes to `/`, and doesn't allow me to click on other links.

Anybody have any suggestions or ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Where is router-outlet in your component?

Comment: @SurajKhanal I have `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in my main app shell.  I've simplified my code above, but my application has multiple router modules that I use. I mainly need a URL for the dialog so the user can easily share information to other users.

Comment: Add <router-outlet> to your FooComponent (parent route component) so that all the children routes are rendered to that compoent

Comment: Hey @SurajKhanal, I modified my original post to be clearer. I already have `<router-outlet>` in my main parent component. The problem the bar component is laced inside an MdDialog and is an overlay over the foo component.

Answer (score 5):

A simple way to achieve that could be as follows

**bar.component.ts**

```typescript
constructor(
  public dialog: MatDialog, 
  @Inject(DOCUMENT) private doc: any, 
  private router: Router) {
  dialog.afterOpen.subscribe(() => {
    if (!doc.body.classList.contains('no-scroll')) {
      doc.body.classList.add('no-scroll');
    }
  });

  this.openModal();
}

openModal() {
  this.dialogRef = this.dialog.open(JazzDialog, this.config);

    this.dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result: string) => {
    this.dialogRef = null;
    this.router.navigate(['../']);
    this.doc.body.classList.remove('no-scroll');
  });
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/6o8UrUwfLIEHBUa3IaBB?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks @yurzui, this is _exactly_ what I was looking for. I was playing with your plunk and noticed that the state of the foo module persists after closing the bar dialog. This is the behavior I am looking for, but I was surprised to see that `navigate` didn't lead to a "fresh" page of foo. Do you know why this happens? Thanks!

Comment: Your plunker doesnt seem to be working.. I am trying to do the same thing.

I'd like to load a dialog at a url, and then when it closes, navigate to the parent state. All I can get to is returning to the root state.

Comment: What does the afterOpen no-scroll do? Why is it needed?

Comment: @Silthus, scroll-bar on the body is usually not desired when a dialog is shown.